# Installing rdd3 to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am just trying to install `rdd` (forensic disk image program) to my Ubuntu 11.10 from source code. But when i try to compile the source code with `./configure`, i am gettin below error:

> checking for OPENSSL... configure: error: Package requirements (openssl >= 0.9.6) were not met:
>   No package 'openssl' found
>   Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>   Alternatively, you may set the environment variables OPENSSL_CFLAGS
>   and OPENSSL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
>   See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Comment: The error message is not useful. There must be some output before "Consider adjusting" that you need to include.

Comment: By the way i have the latest version of openssl.

Comment: So did you try setting OPENSSL_LIBS to point to the right location? Do you have openssl-dev or equivalent installed, too?

Comment: I just installed openssl1.0 from source code. By the way i don't know how to set OPENSSL_LIBS and where to set that variable? @tripleee

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If you want to install rdd3 you should install below packages.

libssl-dev,
libssl-doc,
libssl-ocaml,
libssl-ocaml-dev,
libewf-dev,
doxygen,
xdot,
rdtool,
g++